# Is it possible to have a text file that it is writable only from a java application and read-only from everywhere else?

Tags: java, windows, text, readonly

I have a java application which writes to a text file in my computer. And I want this specific text file to be read-only from everywhere else in my computer(ex. Notepad). Is it possible?

Comment: In a word, no. What is your underlying requirement?

Comment: What do you mean?! My app has a text file and I don't want the user to be able to edit it manually by himself, but only through the app!

Comment: You could handle it using user management of your operation system, create a user witch has `write` access for that file and use that user to run the application which will create the file and write it, *all* other users have only `read` access. If your application is not started with that one user it will fail to write the file.

Comment: That's not an answer, that's just a restatementof what you already said. *Why* does your application have a text file? Why can't you put it into a database for example?

Comment: Yes I know... That would be a solution. I used a text file just to see how it's done with that way...